# Is traveling east in a positive imaginary direction the same thing as traveling north in a positive real direction?

Tags: complex-numbers, soft-question, terminology

So, if someone says, "go $-5$ miles east" you know that that means, "go $5$ miles west". If someone says, "go $5i$ miles east", does that mean "go $5$ miles north"?

Comment: Why would you say that, though?

Comment: Although we commonly think on a map in terms of two-dimensions, and we sometimes think of complex numbers as two-dimensions, we in no way are required or expected to think of the second dimension as being the same in these two scenarios.  I would look at a person saying "go $5i$ miles east" like they were crazy personally.

Comment: It can mean a lot of things.  It can also mean move 5 miles into the Earth, or 5 miles/186,000(miles/second) forward in time. As long as the directions are orthogonal and you preserve handedness, you can define it in many ways.

Comment: It could if you want it to be.  But no-body wants it to be.  @JMoravitz I'll up you one-- I'd look at anyone how says "go -5 miles east" like they were crazy.

Comment: I'm going to vote "no".  On a map the coordinates are not numbers. directions can be added and subtracted but not multiplied.  Yes, you could define comples multiplication (or vector dot product) if you wanted to but there is no intrinsic value to it.  Just as traveling east doesn't set into the anti-matter universe, traveling a mile north is not traversing the distance of of a square root of a negative distance--- or the square root of a easterly direction which .... just doesn't *mean* anything.

Answer (score 1):

That's a strange but interesting question. I think that with the right conventions a reasonable answer is "yes".

Start by thinking about the complex numbers in the usual way as the Euclidean coordinate plane. Then it's reasonable to think of the four compass directions ENWS as specifying travel parallel to the coordinate axes in the obvious way. "Adding $5$" to any complex number takes you five units to the right (east). "Adding $5i$" to any complex number takes you five units up (north).

Then of course "go $5$ miles northeast" is the same as "go $5/\sqrt{2}$ miles east,
 then $5/\sqrt{ 2}$ miles north", or just "go $5(1+i)/\sqrt{2}$".

All in all, somewhat weird but a nice idea.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the complex numbers are associated with the **complex plane** in which the Cartesian coordinates $(a, b)$ are identified with $a + bi$. Associating the plane with the standard orientation of a North-South-East-West map, I can see why traveling east or west could be associated with real numbers (just as real numbers are often depicted on the **number line**, i.e., a horizontal line) but it seems to me that, from this perspective, the imaginary numbers would be better referred to as being north or south.

**That said:** This terminology seems to me quite nonstandard, so I would not expect any of North, South, East, or West to be readily interpreted in the context of "complex" directions.